# Changing resolution

Tags: 14.04, display, xrandr, display-resolution

Im trying to get Ubuntu to run at a higher resolution using `xrandr` and am having problems. I do fine when I run:

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_59.90" 106.29 1440 1520 1672 1904 900 901 904 932 -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1440x900_59.90
```

But if I try to go to 1920x1080 using the same command I get about 2.5 inches of unused monitor on the left side. Am I using the wrong resolution? I have a 24 inch class HDTV I am using as a monitor and according to Ubuntu it has a max resolution of 8192x8192, so I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/664012/second-screen-resolution-nvidia-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

TV's are notoriously bad monitors (since the [ZX80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX80))

You should look up how to turn off the TV's over/underscan option in your TV's manual or on it's support site.  If it's hanging on a wall, use a digital camera to take a picture from the back-side so you have the exact model number.